# Reporting Services 2012 - display user name on Report Manager main page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportmanager

We have Reporting Services 2012 in native mode. Is there a way to display name of a user that is currently logged into Report Manager (http://myserver.com/reports)?
I know that user name can be displayed on a report.
But I need to display the name on the home page of report manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I got from msdn forum:

> You can only show the name within reports not in the report manager.
>   If you want to show it in report portal screen you need to use a custom viewer using .NET application.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1d493bc8-420d-4dcd-a88a-8b2b69d057aa/reporting-services-2012-display-user-name-on-report-manager-main-page?forum=sqlreportingservices